# Excel Find Nth Instance of Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 columns of data. Col A contains Names, Col B contains a client ID, Col C contains a date.

I'm trying to figure out how to write a formula that will find the top 2 and top 3 instances of a specific Name in Col A and client ID in Col B and return the value in Col C.

Trying to avoid using VBA, but not sure if this is doable.

So for example data looks like this and I would want to return that Sam dealt with Client ABC the 2nd time around on 12/16.

Sam  ABC  12/3

Adam  XYZ  12/5

John  DEF  12/9

Sam  ABC  12/16

Adam  HIJ  12/18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming

- your headers are in A1:C1
- your data starts from A3 (yes, not A2)
- You enter the name in G2 & Client ID in G3 & you want the list of
  dates starting from G5

Enter these formula/values:

- A2: `=G2`
- B2: `=G3`
- C2: `=0`
- G5:
  `=IFERROR(INDEX(($A$2:$A$500=$G$2)*($B$2:$B$500=$G$3)*($C$2:C$500),MATCH(0,COUNTIF($G$4:G4,($A$2:$A$500=$G$2)*($B$2:$B$500=$G$3)*($C$2:C$500)),0)),"End")`

(Formula in G5 is an array formula; confirm this with Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

Drag the formula in G5 down until you see 'End'

Value in cell G5 will always be 0 or '1/0' based on your formatting.

The list of dates corresponding to the name & client ID combination will start from G6.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understood your need. Correct me if I'm wrong.

You want to be able to inform a Name and a Client ID and have Excel tell you the last 3 occurrences of that combination?

By "top 2 and top 3 instances of a specific name" I'm assuming you mean the top 2 and 3 dates found for that specific name and ID.

If so, try this:

Supposing you have your example data table starting at Cell A1 and ending at Cell C6 (including column headers) and that you'll enter the name in F1 and Client ID on F2

A                    B                    C
1 Name         Client ID          Date
2 Sam                 ABC                12/3
3 Adam              XYZ               12/5
4 John                 DEF               12/9
5 Sam              ABC                12/16
6 Adam              HIJ               12/18

Type this formula where you want to return the date of the last occurrence:

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$6=$F$1,IF($B$2:$B$6=$F$2,$C$2:$C$6)),1),"-")
```

This should be entered as an **Array Formula**, so don't forget to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or it'll not work.

To bring the 2nd last occurrence on another cell, just copy and paste the formula and change the number 1  to 2 (as indicated below):

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$6=$F$1,IF($B$2:$B$6=$F$2,$C$2:$C$6)),2),"-")
```

If you typed 'Sam' on F1 and 'ABC' on F2, this formula would return '12/16' as the last occurrence, '12/3' as the 2nd last occurrence and a dash (-) as the 3rd last occurrence, since there isn't one.

Of course, you'll have to adjust the ranges and other cell references accordingly in your real data set.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry about that, I wasn't clear.  I would just want the dates based on the order they appear in the list.  So 1st occurrence would be 12/3 because its the first occurrence of the Same/ABC combination... 2nd would be 12/16.  I'd like to be able to use this formula to retrieve other column data and not just date. Does this make sense?

Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Ok, so let's check again. You'll inform Sam and ABC and you want something in your worksheet to tell you that the 1st occurrence of that combination was on 12/3, the 2nd on 12/16 and so on? And then use this info to retrieve other column data based on these dates?  Sorry if I'm asking too much, I just want to understand your situation to help you.

Comment: Hi Gerson, That's exactly it. I tried this after doing some research online but it is incorrect. =INDEX($G$2:$G$300,MATCH(2,(J$1=$C$2:$C$300)*($I8=$D$2:$D$300),0))